# Plot value near point matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following graph in in which there is the average bpm in relation to the listening day. I want to plot near the point the exact value of mean. How can I do it?

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPJ8G.png)

What I expect in output is:

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2xbG.png)

This is the code I wrote:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", sep = ';')
bpmFriday= df.tempo

x = df .date.iloc[0]    
bpmMean = bpmFriday.mean()

first= plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.title('BPM mean (Friday)')
plt.scatter(x, bpmMean )
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plt.text(x, y, s)` where `s` is the text you want to display and `x` and `y` are the text coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = '2021-12-25'
bpmMean = 420

first= plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.title('BPM mean (Friday)')
plt.scatter(x, bpmMean )
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

# plt.annotate(s=bpmMean, xy=(x, bpmMean+.5))

plt.text(x=x, y=bpmMean+0.5, s=bpmMean) # y=bpmMean+0.5 for readibility
```

Comment: thanks it was just what I was looking for